# Degree of minimal polynomial of the sum of two algebraic elements over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

The minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is quadratic.

The minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is cubic.

Is the minimal polynomial of $a+b$ necessarily of degree $6$?

If so, what is the shortest/most elegant proof of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the degrees of sums in separable field extensions multiply, if they are relatively prime, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjTp8O-porxAhVoxIsKHUuGCZAQFjACegQIAhAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pdmi.ras.ru%2F%7Elowdimma%2Ftopics_nth%2FIsaacs70.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2hkSlusYQFnXGO4jPD74cq). Since $\gcd(2,3)=1$ we obtain, that the degree of $a+b$ is equal to $2\cdot 3=6$, and
$\mathbb{Q}(a,b)=\mathbb{Q}(a+b)$.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. Do you know if this proof, which uses Galois theory, is really the simplest we can do here?

Comment: I was actually wondering if we can solve this without making use of Galois theory - this seems a bit of an overkill for this elementary question, doesn't it?

Comment: It is not so elementary for arbitary $n$ and $m$; and only this is really interesting, I think. This is, what many students want to know. Galois theory also is quite appropiate when dealing with questions from field theory.

Comment: I know what Galois theory is about, and while I appreciate that it might be the appropriate approach in the general case, I'm definitely not convinced that we actually need to mention the word Galois in the 2,3 characteristics zero case.

Comment: I think, the word Galois should be mentioned here, but I accept your opinion. By the way, the proof is trivial in general, if at least one of the fields $\mathbf{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(b)$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ - which is here the case for a degree $2$ extension.

Comment: The link leads to the paper I.M. Isaacs, *Degrees of sums in a separable field extension*.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $c= a+b$. It is enough to show that $\mathbb{Q}(c) = \mathbb{Q}(a,b)$, the last one easily seen to be of degree $6$. The proof involves the standard trick, but we need a bit of work.

Let $P$ the minimal polynomial of $a$, with root $a=a_1$, $a_2$, and $Q$ the minimal polynomial of $b$, with roots $b=b_1$,$b_2$, $b_3$.
Consider now the polynomial 
$P(c - X)$. It has the root $b_1$. Let's show that it doesn't have any other commons roots with $Q$. It it did, we would have 
$P(c-b_2) = 0$, so say $c-b_2= a_2$, or 
$$a_1 + b_1= a_2 + b_2$$ or
$$b_2 = b_1 + (a_1 - a_2)$$
Now, $(a_1-a_2) = \sqrt{d}$. So $Q(b + \sqrt{d}) = 0$. Now
$$Q(b+ \sqrt{d}) = Q(b) + Q'(b) \sqrt{d} + \frac{1}{2}Q''(b)d + \frac{1}{6}Q^{(3)}(b) d \sqrt{d}=\\
\left(Q'(b) +  \frac{1}{6}Q^{(3)}(b)\right) \sqrt{d} + \frac{1}{2}Q''(b)d$$
Now $Q'(b) +  \frac{1}{6}Q^{(3)}(b)\ne 0$, since $b$ is of degree $3$. It follows that $\sqrt{d}\in \mathbb{Q}(b)$, contradiction.

Therefore, the GCD of the polynomials $P(c-X)$  $Q$ is $X-b$. Therefore, this polynomial must be in $\mathbb{Q}(c)[X]$, so $b \in \mathbb{Q}(c)$. 
This also gives an effective way to find the expression of $b$ in terms of $c$.

Observation: From the above, we conclude: if $b$, $e$ are irrationals of degree $3$, then the only possibilities for the degrees of $b+e$ are $1$, $3$, $6$, $9$ ( never $2$).

Note that the proof works for 
$\deg a = 2$ and $\deg b$ odd.