# Does $K(a,b)=K(a+b)$ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $F=K(a,b)$, $F/K$ is an extension field and $a,b\in F$ are algebraic over $K$ with $\deg(\mathrm{Irr}(a,K))=2$ and $\deg(\mathrm{Irr}(b,K))=3$. I am asked to calculate the degree of the extension $F/K$, denoted by $|F:K|$, and to prove that $F=K(a+b)$.

I have been able to prove that $|F:K|=6$, since $|K(a):K|=2$, $|K(b):K|=3$ and $\gcd(2,3)=1$.

However, I do not know how to approach the second part of the problem. Since not much information of the elements $a$ and $b$ is given, I have been trying to prove that $|K(a+b):K|=6$, but I have not been able to do it.

Any hints as to how to approach this problem would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's clear that $K(a + b) \subseteq F$, what are the possible degrees of $K(a+b)$ over $K$?

Comment: @Quimey I know the possible degrees are 1,2,3, and 6. I know how to discard 1, but not 2 nor 3.

Comment: If the degree is 2 then $K(a + b) = K(a)$, what do you get from there?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen my bad, I thought it was evident that $K(a) \subseteq K(a + b)$ but it's not obvious.

Comment: It actually follows that $F/K$ cannot have two intermediate fields of degree two. For their compositum would be an intermediate field of degree four. So Quimey's suggestion then implies that you cannot have $[K(a+b):K]=2$. However, there may well be several degree three intermediate fields with pairwise compositums equal to $F$ (think: splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$). This means that a different argument is needed.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2446253/11619).

Comment: Mind you Orangeskid's argument does not work for all fields. Inseparable cases need modifications, I think.

Comment: Is $K$ of characteristic $0$?